# Uploading files to public google cloud storage bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload files to a google storage bucket. The bucket has public access and I am able to upload files to it using gsutil. However, when trying to retrieve bucket information in python using:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client.create_anonymous_client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('gcp-public-data-landsat')
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError("Anonymous credentials cannot be refreshed.")
```

I have tried the above with both the public google bucket (gcp-public-data-landsat) and a private public bucket I am using and both give the same error.

Do I need to authenticate in some way, although using anonymous access?
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078146/how-to-properly-use-create-anonymous-client-function-in-google-cloud-storage-p

Comment: I currently am unable to change the permissions to both bucket and it gives the same error for both public buckets, so I believe there is a way to access it publicly and this isnt a permissions issue